# Insert,Update,Retrive using stored procedures or functions in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Check whether the primary key exists in the table.

1. If exists retrieve three column values and update the three column values with new values.

   ```
   String sql = "SELECT brno, brdate, type1,type,flag,mcode,pamount,tax,pamount1,liab FROM rawdata WHERE mcode="+mcode;

   ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

   rs.first();
   float oldPamount= rs.getFloat("pamount");
   float tax= rs.getFloat("tax");
   float oldPamount1= rs.getFloat("pamount1");

   float newPamount= pamount;
   float newTax= tax;
   float newPamount1= pamount1;
   rs.updateFloat("pamount", newPamount);
   rs.updateFloat("tax", newTax);
   rs.updateFloat("pamount1", newPamount1);
   rs.updateRow();
   ```
2. If not exists insert the record and retrieve it.
   I have tried this:

   ```
   INSERT INTO rawdata (brno, brdate, type1,type,flag,mcode,pamount,tax,pamount1,liab)

   SELECT * FROM (SELECT '1', '02.05.15', 'G','H','E','2222','789.00','0.00','789.00','L') AS tmp
           WHERE NOT EXISTS (
               SELECT mcode FROM rawdata WHERE mcode = '2222'
           );
   ```

But it getting the following error duplicate value 789.00

I need to done these things at a time not separate queries.

This is my table(rawdata) with fields(brno, brdate, type1,type,flag,mcode,pamount,tax,pamount1,liab) where mcode is the primarykey

Here the pamount,tax,pamount1 need to be updated if the record exists.

For Ex:

These are the sample values `873.00,0.00,873.00` needed to be updated to `789.00,0.00,789.00` (or) `24000.00,240.00,23760.00`

Other wise need to insert entire row for the new mcode

I have tried the above queries, but i need to be done at time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not a coding service.

Comment: you should show some of your efforts first.

Comment: please check this answer on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4205207/4236400

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert to table or update if exists (MySQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql)

Comment: @RenéHoffmann how to retrive the value before updating i.e not there in your answer